# How to create list of city as individual in DEAP Python?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am starting with DEAP in Python and I pretend to implement a GA to solve [TSP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

I want to know if it is possible to create a list with name of city (Strings) as Individual. For example, an individual can be: `["Madrid","Paris","London","Rome"]`.

At this moment, I represent the cities with integers:

```
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

    IND_SIZE=8

    toolbox = base.Toolbox()
    toolbox.register("indices", random.sample, range(IND_SIZE), IND_SIZE) 
    toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indices)
```

Comment: As a general comment, you could have a look at Peter Norvig's excellent walk-through of the TSP in a Jupyter Notebook. https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/ipynb/TSP.ipynb

He reflects on the representation of a complete tour.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. My target is a bit different. I pretend to learn DEAP. At this moment, the cities are integers and it works fine. I would like to know about use string for cities. In that link I do not find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible approach. I declare a new function as given below:

```
def generate_individual():
    return ["Almeria","Cadiz","Cordoba","Granada","Huelva","Jaen","Malaga", "Seville"]
```

To declare individual:

```
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("indices", generate_individual) # Gen, in this case, a number which represents a city.
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indices) # Define a route of cities. A chromosome.
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
POP_SIZE = 50
pop = toolbox.population(n=POP_SIZE)
```

The output is as given below:

```
[['Almeria', 'Cadiz', 'Cordoba', 'Granada', 'Huelva', 'Jaen', 'Malaga', 'Seville'], ..., ['Almeria', 'Cadiz', 'Cordoba', 'Granada', 'Huelva', 'Jaen', 'Malaga', 'Seville']]
```